# Handling "Accept Cookies" popup with Selenium in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

I'm using Selenium to sign-in to a website and send messages in it. However, the website always shows a cookie popup and I don't know how to press the accept button to proceed on the website.

This is the image of the
[popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9QW0.png)

This is the HTML corresponding to the accept button:

```
<button class="GdprNotification__LinkButton-nj3w6j-1 hRrekE" data-testid="gdpr-accept-button">Accept</button>
```

I tried doing this

```
browser.findElement(By.className("GdprNotification__LinkButton-nj3w6j-1 hRrekE")).click();
```

But it just gives me this error message

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchElementError: Unable to locate element: button.GdprNotification__LinkButton-nj3w6j-1 hRrekE
```

Answer (score 0):

`By.className` won't take multiple classnames. Additionally, as the element is a dynamic element you have to use `await`.

---

### Solution

You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath`:

  ```
  await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@data-testid='gdpr-accept-button']")
  ```

More canonically,

- `xpath`:

  ```
  await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@data-testid='gdpr-accept-button' and text()='Accept']")
  ```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I'm getting this error:
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchElementError: Unable to locate element: //button[@data-testid='gdpr-accept-button' and text()='Accept']
It's weird because I put the code after I input the password, yet this error occurs before the password is even sent to the website. Any suggestions?